# How to infinitely zoom in on a Chart3D?

Tags: lightningchart

I am using a 3D chart, and I found that it can keep zooming out infinitely, but there's a limit to how much I can zoom in using the mouse wheel.I sometimes need to zoom in to observe a specific portion of the chart, even if a part of the 3D chart extends beyond the container

Infinite zoom on the chart

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a limit to zoom in capability in 3D charts. I imagine its mainly there as zooming far inside the 3D box may provide little usability since the zooming is always targeted to the center of the box rather than some specific user region of interest.

If this is a problem to you, maybe you could elaborate the use case and how it could work better?